# writable mount encrypted obb with StorageManager in Android

Tags: android, encryption, mount, apk-expansion-files, writable

1. I need to mount an obb encrypted file **writable**. Mounting an encrypted obb works just fine but is always readable, so i can't delete files or modify them

   ```
   getApplication().getSM().mountObb(mExpansionFile.getAbsolutePath(),
                                      getPass(), mOnObbStateChangeListener);
   ```
2. Perhaps there is a specific way to create obb files to be mounted writable. Mine obbs are created with the jobb tool.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22866616/error-error-could-not-mount-mounting-obb-on-some-devices, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21161475/can-mount-unencrypted-obb-but-with-encrypted-error-21

Comment: see https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61881