# Error ERROR_COULD_NOT_MOUNT mounting obb on some devices

Tags: android, mount

We have an unencrypted obb file that is giving us problems on the Droid Maxx when running Android 4.4.  It seems fine on the same device running Android 4.1.  It is also fine on a range of other devices running anything from Android 4.0.1 to 4.4.2.

The problem is that when we try to mount the obb, we always get back ERROR_COULD_NOT_MOUNT in the OnObbStateChangeListener.  If we call isObbMounted() we get back false.

I know people have had problems with mounting encrypted obbs, but as I said, this one's not.  Anyone have any thoughts on why this failed on the Maxx?  Is mounting just broken on that device?

FWIW: We have also had reports of problems on rooted devices running very recent ROMS of SlimKat

Bill

Comment: I can confirm this issue on Nexus 4 with Android 4.4.4. Also getting error 21 (ERROR_COULD_NOT_MOUNT).

Comment: see https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61881